# Pass a function as a final parameter

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby.
I have been trying out shoes and have seen many times function calls in this fashion:

```
somefunc "someparameter", "otherparameter" do
    SomeFunctionContents
end
```

How can I create a function which takes such a function as a final argument, in the same fashion?
I would like to be able to call it like:

```
myFunction "myParameter" do
    SomeStuffIWouldLikeToCallInMyFunction
end
```

How would I achieve this?

My attempt so far has been:

```
def myfunc parameterone
    doStuff
    yield # In order to call the function passed after parameteone
    doStuff
end
# AND LATER
myfunc "parameterone" def
    myFuncStuff
end
```

Which simply does not function.

**EDIT**
Although my problem has been solved, for the sake of clarity I will supply the error message, as this may be useful for anyone making the same mistake.

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_def, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: Why are you using `def` in your last example, but `do`, which is correct, in the previous ones? Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Wow. That was my entire mistake. Thank you, that fixed it. I was using `def` all the time, forgetting that the proper syntax is `do`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We call that blocks.

```
def call_this_block
  stuff = 'can be anything'
  yield stuff
end

call_this_block { |x|
  puts 'you can use brackets'
  puts x
}

call_this_block do |x|
  puts 'or you can use do/end blocks'
  puts x
end
```

Also, calling `Proc.new` without arguments will emulate the passed block

```
def call_this_block
  Proc.new.call(111)
end

call_this_block { |x| x ** 3 }
```

I think your mistake lays in a misunderstanding of what `def` does. In ruby we have methods and anonym functions, and although the are like close cousins, they are not the same.

```
# def defines a method a attaches it to the current scope
def this_method
  puts 'asdf'
end

# this method is "attached" so you can retrieve it at any time and even redefine it
method(:this_method)
=> #<Method: Object#this_method> # Object is the default scope where you are sitting

# call it
method(:this_method).call
this_method

# this one of the many available syntaxis to create anonym functions or methods 
that_method = -> { puts 'is not attached' }
that_method.call
```

Answer (score 2):

As @nicooga indicated they are called blocks in Ruby. You can use the "block_given?" to detect if a block was passed to the function when it was called and then yield.

```
def sayHello 
  puts "hello"
  if block_given?
    yield
  end
  puts "hello again"
end

# pass a block to it
sayHello do 
  puts "(exectute some task)"
end

# don't pass a block to it
sayHello
```